# How can I create an Alarm Clock on iOS with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

It seems so much easier to create an alarm clock that sends an notification on Android, but so much harder on iOS. Anyone got any ideas on how to do that on iOS? Which packages should i use , etc...

Answer (score 0):

To create an alarm clock on iOS using Flutter, you will need to use the `flutter_local_notifications` plugin. This plugin allows you to schedule and display notifications within your Flutter app. Here are the basic steps to create an alarm clock:

1. Install the flutter_local_notifications plugin by adding it to your pubspec.yaml file and running "flutter packages get"
2. Import the plugin in your Dart code and initialize it
3. Use the plugin's schedule method to schedule a notification for the desired alarm time
4. Handle the notification when it is displayed, such as by playing an alarm sound

You can find more detailed instructions and sample code in the flutter_local_notifications documentation and examples.